# Trendnet TFM-561U modem permissions

Tags: modem-manager

How do I give myself permission to use my modem in my machine?  I am trying to use efax-cgt to send faxes and don't have permission to use the modem.

How can that be?

ted@ted-desktop:~$ id
uid=1000(ted) gid=1000(ted) groups=1000(ted),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
ted@ted-desktop:~$

Comment: Please include the output of the command `id` run from a terminal by [edit]ing your question. This should show to what groups you are a member of.

Comment: ted@ted-desktop:~$ id
uid=1000(ted) gid=1000(ted) groups=1000(ted),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
ted@ted-desktop:~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modem device is probably registered as a TTY or ACM device. These can be found in `/dev` like this:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Nov  3 09:37 /dev/ttyS0
[...]
```

Notice the permissions set to `root` and the `dialout` group for the example listed. To be able to read/write to the device as a regular user, just make sure you're a member of this group. Several options to do this exist: through the user management in system settings or command line like this:

```
sudo adduser username dialout
```

Then log out of your Ubuntu session and log back in (or simply reboot) to make this change effective.

In case of trouble, check with `id` whether you're indeed a member and verify with `ls -l` on the device what permissions you need. In the unlikely case your modem driver doesn't use the regular ACM/serial driver interfacing, edit your question to include these details (we don't have this specific modem).